# Segmentation fault on requests.request

Tags: python, gdb, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, urllib3

I am getting a segmentation fault after using python requests library to connect to Twitter's v2 API endpoint.

The request is created on a separate thread in a generator object

```
class TwitterStream:
    def __init__():
        self.response = self.build_response()    

    def build_response():
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers, stream=True)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception("Exception")
        for record in response.iter_lines():
            yield record

    def __next__():
        return next(self.response)
```

Then on the execution thread, I use a ThreadPoolExecutor to get each response line:

```
record_future = threadpoolexecutor.submit(next, TwitterStreamObjectInstance)
if record_future.done():
   # do stuff  with record_future.result()
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault at the `response = requests.request("GET", url, headers, stream=True)` line, I'm pretty sure, based on a lot of `print()` debugging.

I tried the gdb debugging method, and got back this stacktrace -- I am assuming libssl.so.1 is causing this problem, but I don't really know how to investigate this further.

```
#0  0x000000000001d85e in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff406ffa0 in OPENSSL_init_ssl () from /mnt/d/Projects/EBKA/edna_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/vendor/libssl.so.1.1
#2  0x00007ffff4074be3 in SSL_CTX_new () from /mnt/d/Projects/EBKA/edna_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/vendor/libssl.so.1.1
#3  0x00007ffff43c855d in ?? () from /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#4  0x00005555556c9ff2 in ?? ()
#5  0x00005555556857d0 in _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords ()
#6  0x0000555555685560 in _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
#7  0x00005555556fa4e4 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#8  0x00005555556f4e2f in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName ()
#9  0x0000555555687591 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend ()
#10 0x00005555556c9e3c in ?? ()
#11 0x00005555556c5ce5 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000555555685f72 in _PyObject_FastCallKeywords ()
#13 0x00005555556fa00d in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#14 0x00005555556f4e2f in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName ()
#15 0x0000555555686efa in _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
#16 0x00005555556f6b0a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#17 0x0000555555686e1a in _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
.
.
.
#58 0x00005555555c5d24 in _PyFunction_FastCallDict ()
#59 0x00005555556f73d0 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#60 0x0000555555686e1a in _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
#61 0x00005555556f5fde in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#62 0x0000555555686e1a in _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords ()
#63 0x00005555556f5fde in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#64 0x0000555555687359 in _PyObject_Call_Prepend ()
#65 0x00005555556879b8 in PyObject_Call ()
#66 0x0000555555800193 in ?? ()
#67 0x00005555557c30d7 in ?? ()
#68 0x00007ffff7bbb6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fffd0f92700) at pthread_create.c:463
#69 0x00007ffff6cf071f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

---

A side note -- I have been having a problem with closing threads, where I get the following

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

A suggestion I got was to do the following in the beginning of execution:

```
import ctypes
libgcc_s = ctypes.CDLL('libgcc_s.so.1')
```

but this didn't work. The reason I mention this is because after I tried this, I kept getting a "cannot find libssl" error, and I am not sure if it would be related.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience crashes in `OPENSSL_init_ssl` most often result from linking in more than one version (or more than one instance) of `libssl.so.x.y` into a single process.

Use GDB `info shared libssl` at crash point.

If you see more than one version, that's very likely the root cause.

If you don't, it's still possible that some of your binaries link in `libssl.a`. For each binary (the main `python` executable and every shared library in `info shared` output), run `nm -A python lib1.so lib2.so ... | grep OPENSSL`.

If the only matching library is `/mnt/d/Projects/EBKA/edna_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/vendor/libssl.so.1.1`, then there must be some other root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I solved for Mac M1 like this:

```
$ apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev
$ pip install pyopenssl
```

Comment: `apt-get` on macOS?

Comment: inside the container of course.